# Difference between these two implementations of Insertion Sort

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I feel these two implementations are doing the same thing, but would be great if you can also let me know if they are (performance wise) doing the same thing (e.g. in terms of number of instructions executed). Thanks.

```
<?php

$arr = array(10, 2, 3, 14, 16);

function sortOne($arr) {

    $instructionCount = 0;

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $instructionCount++;
        for ($j = $i - 1; $j >= 0 && ($arr[$j] > $arr[$i]); $j--) {
            $instructionCount++;

            $tmp = $arr[$i];
            $arr[$i] = $arr[$j];
            $arr[$j] = $tmp;

        }
    }

    echo "\nTotal Instructions for Sort One: $instructionCount\n"; 

    return $arr;
}

function sortTwo($array) {

    $instructionCount = 0;

    for($j=1; $j < count($array); $j++){
        $instructionCount++;
        $temp = $array[$j];
        $i = $j;
        while(($i >= 1) && ($array[$i-1] > $temp)){
            $instructionCount++;
            $array[$i] = $array[$i-1];
            $i--;
        }
        $array[$i] = $temp;
    }

    echo "\nTotal Instructions for Sort Two: $instructionCount\n"; 

    return $array;
}


var_dump(sortOne($arr));
```

Comment: I just want to point out that you can use [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function to sort your array

Comment: thanks @AmrAly I know that but I am interested in the algorithm analysis otherwise would definitely use the library function

Comment: @SoftwareGuy Your first function does not sort the array correctly.

Comment: @SumeetSingh Can you please elaborate? If I run the code I posted, the array is sorted just fine when I run the first function. Why do you think it does not sort correctly when for me it does sort? Thanks

Comment: @SoftwareGuy Run your code separately for the two functions and then see the output. Maybe its getting sorted as a result of second function which is correct.

Comment: @SoftwareGuy You could run your code manually on array [4,3,1], Clearly the output is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @SumeetSingh running with the array [4,3,1] helped me verify. It indeed is wrong and doesn't work with all arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No they are not the same**. The function `sortOne` is **wrong implementation** of `insertion sort`.

The correct implementation of function `sortOne` is:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $instructionCount++;
    $temp = $arr[$i];
    for ($j = $i - 1; $j >= 0 && ($arr[$j] > $temp); $j--) {
        $instructionCount++;
        $arr[$j + 1] = $arr[$j];                
    }
    $arr[$j + 1] = temp;
}
```

Considering the performance now, they basically have equal performance. Just by changing for loop to while loop, you wont be getting any performance change.

Comment: Thanks @Sumeet. Can you please explain how moving the $temp variable declaration and final assignment out of the inner loop made a difference? If the implementation is wrong, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @SoftwareGuy In insertion sort , we insert ith element in already sorted array[0.....i-1], meaning array that is sorted till position i - 1. When we find a bigger element in position 0 to i - 1, we move it at bigger position. But the comparison is always done with element at position i, which stays constant and for that we have to use temp variable instead of actual element.

Comment: Thanks @Sumeet - found my mistake thanks to your clarification. I've accepted the answer. Thanks yar!